# How to calculate this maximum

Tags: python, numpy

I have two one-dimensional arrays `u` and  `q` as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
n = 300
u1 = np.random.uniform(0.5, 4.5, size=n)
u2 = 2 / u1 + np.random.normal(scale=0.09, size=n)
u = np.array([u1,u2])
```

and

```py
d=np.random.uniform(0.0, np.pi, size=100)
q = np.array([np.cos(d), np.sin(d)])
```

How can I calculate the maximum `max_{ui,uj\in U} |qm^T (ui -uj)|` for each `m` from 1 to 100 where `ui` and `uj` are two arbitrary colomns of `u` and `qm^T` is the transpose of the `m`th colomn `qm` of `q`?

**What I've tried:**

I tried `np.max(abs(np.dot(q.transpose(), u-u)))` but the answer was `0`. I don't know how to vary the columns of `u` to make `ui-uj`.

Comment: Is your question how to write `u - u` properly, or how to compute the maximum?

Comment: What shape result do you expect? Can you show a reference implementation using loops?